# how to get value of first item in table row on a rows dropdown change

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get some data in jQuery to submit via ajax. I have a table, the first element in each row has a class of sorting and the value is the id of the client. The last element is a dropdown. When the dropdown is clicked the on-change event is fired and I'm able to get the selected value of the dropdown but I've been struggling to get the client id value. Here's my code

```
<table id="clients" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>option</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="sorting">1</td>
            <td>
                <select class="option" name="option">
                    <option value="0">Please Choose...</option>
                    <option value="y">Yes</option>
                    <option value="n">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="sorting">2</td>
            <td>
                <select class="option" name="option">
                    <option value="0">Please Choose...</option>
                    <option value="y">Yes</option>
                    <option value="n">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#clients" ).on("change", ".option", function() {
            option = this.value;
            alert( $( this ).parent().find( '.sorting' ).val() );
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried a few things to get this id but nothing has worked. Mainly (as in this case) the alert says undefined.

I've not yet done the ajax post request and I'm pretty familiar with that but there is no point if I cannot get the id that has changed value.

thanks

Comment: `$( this ).parent()` - `this` is the `<select>` element, hence `.parent()` returns the `<td>`. You need the "closest" `<tr>`, so the parent of the `<td>`

Comment: [Traversing | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Comment: `alert( $( this ).closest('tr').find( '.sorting' ).text() );` try it

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the link on traversing, very helpfiul

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clients").on("change", ".option", function() {
    option = this.value;
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.sorting').text());
    alert($(this).parent().siblings('.sorting').text());
    alert($(this).parent().prev('.sorting').text()); //[recommended as less traversal happen]
  });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to be more specific to find your selector. parent() give you only one level parent element so you got td not tr. instead parent() use parents('tr') to get the tr element. remember td is not having any value so you need to get the text using text() method.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#clients" ).on("change", ".option", function() {
        option = this.value;
        alert( $( this ).parents('tr').find( '.sorting' ).text() );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, It is now returning the id. was the value() that had me

Comment: As a sidenote, why does val not work in a td?

Comment: The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty collection, it returns undefined.